# jQuery event 'on' another custom event?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a Wordress theme (TheGem) and I want to attach some custom code when some theme jQuery happens.

Can I use `on` to attach my code to some other existing code? I.e. could I, in my page, do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("$.pageScroller.next()", function() {
     console.log("it's working!");
   });
});
```

Background: I all I want to do is hide the logo while the page is scrolled to the top. I usually use:

```
<script>
jQuery(window).scroll( function() {
    if( jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
        show_logo();
    }
    else {
        hide_logo();
    }
});

function hide_logo() {
    jQuery(".site-title .site-logo a .logo img").css('visibility', 'hidden');
}

function show_logo() {
    jQuery(".site-title .site-logo a .logo img").css('visibility', 'visible');
}
</script>
```

But this particular site has vertical full-pane scrolling enabled and I don't believe the pages actually 'scrolls' so I'm hoping to hook into whatever displays the next section. In this case, that is `$.pageScroller.next()`

The JS for the code I'm trying to attach to below in full.

```
(function($){

    $.pageScroller = {

        items: $('.scroller-block'),
        navigationPane: null,
        activeItem: 0,
        animated: false,

        init: function() {
            var that = this;
            $('body').css({overflow: 'hidden'});
            $(window).trigger('resize');
            if(that.items.length) {
                that.navigationPane = $('<div class="page-scroller-nav-pane"></div>');
                that.navigationPane.appendTo($('body'));
                that.items.each(function(index) {
                    var $target = $(this);
                    $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="page-scroller-nav-item"></a>')
                        .appendTo(that.navigationPane)
                        .data('scroller-target', $target)
                        .on('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            that.goTo(index);
                        });
                });
            }
            that.update();
            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                that.update();
            });
        },

        update: function() {
            var that = this;
            if($.pageScroller.navigationPane.is(':visible')) {
                $('html, body').scrollTop(0);
            }
            $('#main').addClass('page-scroller-no-animate');
            $('#main').css('transform','translate3d(0,0,0)');
            that.items.each(function() {
                $(this).data('scroll-position', $(this).offset().top);
            });
            that.goTo(that.activeItem, function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#main').removeClass('page-scroller-no-animate');
                }, 100);
            });
        },

        next: function() {
            this.goTo(this.activeItem + 1);
        },

        prev: function() {
            this.goTo(this.activeItem - 1);
        },

        goTo: function(num, callback) {
            var that = this;
            if(that.animated) return;
            if(num == -1 || num >= this.items.length) return;
            var target_top = this.items.eq(num).data('scroll-position');
            var css = $('#main').css('transform');
            $('#main').css({'transform':'translate3d(0,-'+target_top+'px,0)'});
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(css == $('#main').css('transform')) {
                    that.animated = false;
                    that.activeItem = num;
                    $('.page-scroller-nav-item', that.navigationPane).eq(num).addClass('active');
                    if($.isFunction(callback)) callback();
                    that.updateTrigger(that.items.eq(num));
                    $('#main').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
                }
            }, 50);
            $('.page-scroller-nav-item.active', that.navigationPane).removeClass('active');
            that.animated = true;
            if($('#main').hasClass('page-scroller-no-animate')) {
                that.animated = false;
                that.activeItem = num;
                $('.page-scroller-nav-item', that.navigationPane).eq(num).addClass('active');
                if($.isFunction(callback)) callback();
                that.updateTrigger(that.items.eq(num));
            } else {
                $('#main').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(e) {
                    that.animated = false;
                    that.activeItem = num;
                    $('.page-scroller-nav-item', that.navigationPane).eq(num).addClass('active');
                    if($.isFunction(callback)) callback();
                    that.updateTrigger(that.items.eq(num));
                });
            }
        },

        updateTrigger: function(elem) {
            $(document).trigger('update-page-scroller', elem);
        }

    };

    $(function() {
        if(!$('body').hasClass('compose-mode')) {
            $.pageScroller.init();
            var indicator = new WheelIndicator({
                elem: document.querySelector('body'),
                callback: function(e){
                    if(e.direction == 'up') {
                        $.pageScroller.prev();
                    } else {
                        $.pageScroller.next();
                    }
                }
            });
            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                if($.pageScroller.navigationPane.is(':visible')) {
                    indicator.turnOn();
                } else {
                    indicator.turnOff();
                }
            });
            $('body').swipe({
                allowPageScroll:'vertical',
                preventDefaultEvents: false,
                swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                    if($.pageScroller.navigationPane.is(':visible')) {
                        if(direction == 'down') {
                            $.pageScroller.prev();
                        }
                        if(direction == 'up') {
                            $.pageScroller.next();
                        }
                    }
                },
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, your theme author doesn't trigger any namespaced events that you can hook onto, but fortunately they at least had the decency to attach the `pageScroller` object to `jQuery`

This means that you can monkey patch the code to suit your needs.

looking at the `goTo` function, it seems that they would run a callback function if there were one on the `prev` and `next` functions. There isn't, but you can add them like this:

```
function getPosition(){
   console.log($(window).scrollTop());
}

$.pageScroller = $.extend($.pageScroller,{
    next: function() {
        this.goTo(this.activeItem + 1,getPosition);
    },

    prev: function() {
        this.goTo(this.activeItem - 1,getPosition);
    },
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. `scrollTop()` is always returning 0 (so I was right about no scroll) but I can certainly use that callback to trigger some other logic which will get me what I need :)

Comment: Yeah, this is brilliant. I misunderstood the question, suggested to use Promise objects assuming that `pageScroller` is something that we can have access to. But, just asking. The same thing can be done with Promise objects?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think what we can do is use a `Promise` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) object here.

Posting only the relevant section of the code

```
(function($){
    next: function() {
        let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          this.goTo(this.activeItem + 1);
        });
        promise.then(function(value) {
            console.log("After next() scroll has completed");
        });
    }
});
```

This will basically trigger after the `this.goTo(this.activeItem + 1)` call completes

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else using TheGem Theme with a fullscreen vertical slider page, this is how I now show/hide the header logo. My previous method works on mobile devices because the page actually scrolls, but on larger screens, I'm now using the selected answer to allow me to check if the first slider nav dot is active.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery.extend(jQuery.pageScroller,{
        next: function() {
            this.goTo(this.activeItem + 1, isItFirstSlide);
        },

        prev: function() {
            this.goTo(this.activeItem - 1, isItFirstSlide);
        },
    });   


    function isItFirstSlide() {
        if (jQuery('.page-scroller-nav-pane a').first().hasClass('active')) {
            hide_logo();
        } else {
            show_logo();
        }
    }

    //for mobiles
    jQuery(window).scroll( function() {
        if( jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
            show_logo();
        } else {
            hide_logo();
        }
    });

    function hide_logo() {
        jQuery(".site-title .site-logo a .logo img").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }

    function show_logo() {
        jQuery(".site-title .site-logo a .logo img").css('visibility', 'visible');
    }

});

</script>
```